# Does spring 3 require aspectJ for @Transactional?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-aop

I have a project with `Spring 4` and we have a lot of `@Transactional` classes and methods over there. Everything works perfectly, but I can not to provide transactions driven by `Spring 3` until I add `AspectJ libs` and `special XML configs` in context file. So I would like to know if `Spring 4` implements something like `AspectJ` natively or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATED**

this is xml file for 3d Spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <aop:config proxy-target-class="true" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="saveService" class="com.promptlink.stbtp.dao.billing.SaveService" />
    <bean id="billingDaoImpl" class="com.promptlink.stbtp.dao.billing.BillingDaoImpl" />


    <bean id="dbParams" class="com.promptlink.stbtp.dao.util.SessionManager"
        factory-method="getDbParams">
    </bean>

    <bean id="url" factory-bean="dbParams" factory-method="getBillingUri" />
    <bean id="user" factory-bean="dbParams" factory-method="getUser" />
    <bean id="pass" factory-bean="dbParams" factory-method="getPassword" />
    <bean id="driver" factory-bean="dbParams" factory-method="getDriver" />
    <bean id="dialect" factory-bean="dbParams" factory-method="getDialect" />


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" ref="driver" />
        <property name="url" ref="url" />
        <property name="username" ref="user" />
        <property name="password" ref="pass" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.promptlink.stbtp.dao.billing</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">#{dialect}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <beans profile="webapp">
        <bean id="billingDatabaseProcessor"
            class="com.promptlink.stbtp.dao.statistics.billingReport.BillingDatabaseProcessorImpl"></bean>
    </beans>
</beans>
```

**UPDATED**

For Spring 4 I have something like this for Hibernate

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return SessionManager.getSessionFactory();
    }

}
```

And standard `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` initializer

Comment: Can you provide the configuration files u are using in both the versions?

Comment: @KalyanPradhan  in spring 4 container we have not config file. It is just in spring 3. Spring 4 totally annotation driven. I will update question with XML file right now

Comment: Okay, There must be some java configuration file or else u might be using spring boot while using spring 4. Please update the question with all the configuration files

Comment: Ok I have gone through the XML configuration and want to know how u have configured spring 4, update awaited

Comment: @KalyanPradhan as I know it is the only place where hibernate and spring configuring together

Comment: Ok, good to see the update, do scan your configuration files u might have used @EnableAspectJAutoProxy in some of the configuration file if so do update else the answer is clear and I will post the answer

Comment: @KalyanPradhan unfortunately I dont have such annotation. Even more: I have added AspectJ libs by myself. Until this time there were not this libs on the project. And it seems wired to me. I have to understand if Spring 4 requires this libs for transactions